# php exceptions: how to include more information about problematic sql queries

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, exception

Allright, this is like thousandth time when I get kinda useless information from a php exception. It always looks like this:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1

Stack trace:

#0 /usr/share/php5/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /usr/share/php5/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /usr/share/php5/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `product...', Array)
#3 /usr/share/php5/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(634): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `product...', Array)
#4 /usr/share/php5/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1132): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('products', Array, 'shop = '1' AND ...')
#5 /var/www/simira/html/application/models/DbTable/Products.php(250): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->update(Array, 'shop = '1' AND ...')
#6 /var/www/simira/html/application/controllers/ShopsController.php(567): Application_Model_DbTable_Products->updatePriceByShopCategories(Array, '1')
#7 /var/www/simira/html/application/controllers/ShopsController.php(597): ShopsController->processGlobalChangeRequest('Price', 'Products')
#8 /usr/share/php5/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516): ShopsController->globalChangePriceAction()
#9 /usr/share/php5/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('globalChangePri...')
#10 /usr/share/php5/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#11 /usr/share/php5/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#12 /usr/share/php5/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#13 /var/www/simira/html/public/index.php(29): Zend_Application->run()
#14 {main}
```

What I really need to see now is the query. How can I include this information into an exception being thrown? Can I make it so that the query is not cut away in `query('UPDATE product...', Array)`? I'd like to know if there is a solution I can apply globally. I am on Zend Framework if that helps.

Comment: Your app is not throwing an exception, you have syntax error (looks like quotes). It seems to be happening in Application_Model_DbTable_Products->updatePriceByShopCategories(Array, '1'). Very likely you need to use ->quoteInto() when building queries, or at least this query.

Comment: The error was caused by invalid logic in a condition. I use quote/quoteInto everywhere. But thx.

Comment: The generated query contained `WHERE columnName IN ()` as a result.

Comment: Glad you found it, sometimes debugging sql is a real b#tch. However when the profiler actually works it's great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend Framework includes an awesome DB profiler interface.

My personal favourite is the FirePHP implementation. This shows complete query information in your Firebug console.

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.profiler.html#zend.db.profiler.profilers.firebug

You can also enable MySQL query logging. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html

Comment: wow, that looks easier than I expected. Any chance to have this feature under chrome?

Comment: @clime I haven't tried any of them but you could try one of [these extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/firephp)

Comment: Thx, ill try to set it up under chrome and if that won't be possible, I'll use firefox.

Comment: heh, screw chrome. I have just added these two lines into application.ini: `resources.db.params.profiler.enabled = true`
`resources.db.params.profiler.class = Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug`
and it just magically beautifully works. I abandoned firefox for its memory eating but it looks like he is back!

Comment: err, wait. The query that is causing the exception is not displayed in the console. There is no update, only three selects. How can I display the update query?

Comment: @clime I had a feeling that the profiler wouldn't receive the errant query due to the exception. That's why I suggested enabling the MySQL General Log.

Comment: I am sorrry, but I'll unaccept your answer for now. It is cool stuff but not precisely what I wanted..

Comment: @clime Did you try the MySQL log?

Comment: Yes, I did and i can look at invalid queries now, thank you, but still, I'd prefer to know how to actually modify php exceptions to include that information. If no such answer won't appear, I'll accept again.